# Webpack vendor bundle for lazy loaded chunks

Tags: angular, webpack

We currently building an enterprise Angular application. By default when building and running the application with Angular-CLI all vendor specific code gets bundled into the main.js file.

I wonder if it's possible, when using lazy loaded modules, to bundle the 3pp's that the lazy loaded module is using into a separate js file that gets loaded when the lazy loaded module gets loaded? Instead of bundle them all into the main bundle like they do out of the box in Angular-CLI?

Today's file structure after build:

```
- main.bundle.js - Main application and 3pps for the whole app.
    - 0.chunk.js - Lazy loaded module
```

I'm looking for a solution something like this:

```
- main.bundle.js - Main application and main 3pps (same as today)
    - 0.chunk.js - Lazy loaded module (same as today)
    - 0.chunk.vendor.js - (3pps that's used inside the lazy loaded module)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default settings with webpack 4 optimization, it split the 3 party libraries the lazy loaded module is using into a separate js file already.

```
splitChunks: {
    chunks: "async",
    minSize: 30000,
    minChunks: 1,
    maxAsyncRequests: 5,
    maxInitialRequests: 3,
    name: true,
    cacheGroups: {
        default: {
            minChunks: 2,
            priority: -20
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
        vendors: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            priority: -10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it's possible to do in Webpack 2.4?